# On entry to DLASCLS parameter number 4 had an illegal value

Tags: octave

I do not understand why I get this error and I have googled it but I have not got any satisfactory answers. Many places on google they say it is because the shape of your input data is not good.

My code :

```
%defining variables
N=100;
n=23;
theta=zeros(1,N);
beta=zeros(1,N);
data=[17.88 28.92 33.00 41.52 42.12 45.60 48.40 51.84 51.96 54.12 55.56 67.80 68.64 68.64 68.88 84.12 93.12 98.64 105.12 105.84 127.92 128.04 173.40 ];
x=[0:0.1:2];
i=1;
sum1=0;
sum2=0;
sum3=0;
k=0;
mean_beta=0;
mean_theta=0;

%For the case NO Censoring
%Repeating the experiment to get better results
for k=1:N
    data=sort(data);
    for i=1:n
        t=data(i);
        sum1=sum1+(t.^x)*log(t);
        sum2=sum2+t.^x;
        sum3=sum3+log(t);
    end

    %Calculating Value of Beta        
    f= @(z)(( sum((data(1):data(n)).^z).*(log(data(1):data(n)))/ sum((data(1):data(n)).^z)) - (sum3/n)-(1/z));
    beta(k)=fsolve(f,3.);
    mean_beta=mean_beta+beta(k);

    %Calculating value of Theta
    theta(k)= (sum((data(1):data(n)).^beta(k))/n)^(1/beta(k));
    mean_theta=mean_theta+theta(k);
end

%Final Value
mean_theta=mean_theta/N;
mean_beta=mean_beta/N;
```

Comment: Under Linux, octave 4.0.1 there is no error. What are your octave version, and operating system ? Please note that your example is working, but far from minimal ([mcve]).

Comment: Besides, are you sure you want `(data(1):data(n))` ?